# Fundamental of calculus strong version

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

Why is stronger version of fundamental of calculus?

How is it different from normal?

Comment: The usual FToC requires the integrand to be continuous, while this result relaxes that condition to Riemann integrability.

Comment: Actually, I need the meaning of a ''stronger version''. Why is this style stronger than usual?

Comment: @TheMode "Stronger" means "the other thing follows from this one".